# Using ansible-vault in "interactive mode" via bash script

Tags: bash, ansible, ansible-vault

I really love using `ansible-vault` on the command-line to encrypt/decrypt files easily. For example if I have a plaintext file called `~/fizzbuzz.foo` with the following contents:

```
bupo
```

I can use this tool like so:

```
ansible-vault encrypt ~/fizzbuzz.foo
New Vault password: 123
Confirm New Vault password: 123
```

Boom -- encrypted! When I `vi ~/fizzbuzz.foo` now:

```
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
36663138613666623730653164333138343133383233313562363733346461663334393932393461
6535316532366130316237633633663565663366323162660a666630613738363035343663353132
33383530653235393431633231313765656135626538353163323366363039633836613265383332
3762666261326466370a643164393166346634343636346634383039356665646531353062303765
3734
```

I'd like to use this in a bash script where I pass the encryption/decryption password in as a script argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

# do some stuff

ansible-vault -i "bar" encrypt ~/fizzbuzz.foo

# do some more stuff
```

However I don't see anything like an *interactive* (e.g. `-i`) argument/mode for `ansible-vault`. [The best I could find](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vault.html) was a way of using an env file for storing passwords for the `ansible-playbook` utility but I played around with `ansible-vault` and couldn't find a similar behavior for it.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Are you sure you understand the meaning of the word “interactive”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create the vault password file first, here is how:

`openssl rand -base64 512 |xargs > vaultkeyfile`

i am creating the vault file at local directory, but probably you want to place it to another one, like ~/.ansible_vault/ for example.

then to create/encrypt/decrypt the file, you use:

for new file:

`ansible-vault create testfile.txt --vault-password-file=vaultkeyfile`

for encrypting existing file:

`ansible-vault encrypt testfile.txt --vault-password-file=vaultkeyfile`

for decrypting:

`ansible-vault decrypt testfile.txt --vault-password-file=vaultkeyfile`

when executing the above, you will notice it doesn't ask for password.